# Properly align column in itemize environment inside tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, minipage

I would like to reproduce the following table in LaTeX:

[image: Figure-1]

I decided to use `tabularx` and `minipage` environments. MWE goes as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{15mm}|p{30mm}|p{3mm}|X@{}}
\hline
Row 1
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\\
\hline
Row 2
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But the result is ugly:

- there is very small space between middle horizontal line and first item in the second row
- all horizontal lines are extended over the body of the table

Any pointers or advises are greatly appreciated.

[image: Figure-2]

Comment: You manually specified the size of the columns, in `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{15mm}|p{30mm}|p{3mm}|X@{}}`.  Just increase those sizes, which should give enough space for text to expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you needn't use `minipage`s for this, and you have only three columns but the table setup includes four, I removed that `p{3mm}`. Second, `itemize` environments inside `tabular`s need special settings, so I suggest loading `enumitem` and defining a `newlist` with custom settings to be used only inside `tabular`s. See below how this can be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=*,topsep=0ex,parsep=0pt,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{15mm}|p{30mm}|X@{}|}
\hline
  & column 1 &  column 2 \\ \hline 
Row 1
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{tabitemize}
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{tabitemize} \\ \hline
Row 2
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{tabitemize}
&
\begin{tabitemize}
\item item text foo bla zoo
\item item text foo bla zoo
\end{tabitemize} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]